# Parallelizable spheres are H-spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ho.history-overview, differential-topology

Adams's paper *On the Non-Existence of Elements of Hopf Invariant One* famously includes the following diagram of implications in the introduction:

[Implications in the Hopf Invariant One problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDmfX.png)

I want to focus on the implication (5): $S^{n-1}$ being parallelizable, perhaps with some extraordinary differentiable structure, implies that it is an H-space. Adams attributes this to "A. Dold, in answer to a question of A. Borel," but gives no further reference.

It is not terribly difficult to show this implication: it is carried out, for example, in Haynes Miller's notes on [Vector Fields on Spheres](http://math.harvard.edu/~ecp/latex/misc/haynes-notes/haynes-notes.pdf), Lecture 1. My question is instead one of history:

> Where does this implication first appear in the literature? Is Adams correct about it being due to Dold?

Any pointers to where I can best start sleuthing would be appreciated.

Comment: A proof appears as Lemma 1 of "A Note on Tangent Bundles"
by Kenichi Shiraiwa,  Nagoya Mathematical Journal 1967 https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000024363 (pdf available). He also comments that he could not find a reference.